# Primevue Chart not rendered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js, primevue

Im stuck with rendering Chart from Primevue components. It's based on chart.js library. At this moment I have simple vue component created:

```
<template>
  <div class="p-chart">
    <h2>Chart:</h2>
    <chart type="line" :data="chartData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>

import Chart from "primevue/chart";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: ["Label"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Dataset",
            backgroundColor: "#5F5F5F",
            data: [99],
          },
        ],
      },
    };
  },
  components: {
    Chart,
  },
};
</script>
```

Unfortunately the chart does not appear moreover I don't see any js erros in brwoser console. Can someone help what I'm missing here? Any additional setup needed?

Comment: I am not familiar with this library, but can you try using an uppercase `Chart` when in the HTML?

Comment: @NadirAbbas I fixed the typo and still dont have anything rendered [PrimeVue lib](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/chart)

Comment: Please trying having multiple values in the `data` prop of `dataset`. currently, you have `99` so it might the problem as Line charts need at least two data points to draw a line.

Comment: Thats not the issue, it still draws a point, the scales and the legend, since those are not drawn as well the problem is not that only 1 datapoint is provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove chart.js and then install this version, worked for me (but i use vue 3, maybe you need another version) :

> npm i chart.js@2.9.4

Comment: I am using the same version of Vue 3 and downgrading the chart.js library to the version you suggested made this chart visible. Thank you for this tip! Don't know why on their tutorial suggest using the newest version which doesn't work at all.

Comment: the most weird thing is this: After to install 2.9.4 ver, update chart.js. The version now is the lastest, but the graph is rendered.

Comment: That sounds very strange, I'll stick with the working version :)

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation on https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/chart/line

I think you are missing the options attribute inside Chart tag:

```
<chart type="line" :data="chartData" :options="chartOptions" />
```

And put the object inside the data return from vue export:

```
data() {
    return {
      chartData: {
        labels: ["Label"],
        datasets: [
          {
            label: "Dataset",
            backgroundColor: "#5F5F5F",
            data: [99],
          },
        ],
      },
      chartOptions: {
        plugins: {
          legend: {
            labels: {
              color: '#495057'
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          x: {
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057'
            },
            grid: {
              color: '#ebedef'
            }
          },
          y: {
            ticks: {
              color: '#495057'
            },
            grid: {
              color: '#ebedef'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, unfortunately there is still nothing displayed. I'm wondering is there anything I should initialize to make it visible.

Comment: There is a running code provided by a guy who answer a question of mine https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-primevue-add-data-to-linechart?file=src/App.vue

And here there is the sample running:
https://vue-primevue-add-data-to-linechart.stackblitz.io/

Maybe you should try out the whole project. It can be a configuration related problem.